# i have problom with this func in php

Tags: php, function, oop

```
<?php
function loadModule($module,$action=null,$param=null){
    $access_group = $_SESSION['access_group'];
    $auth_controller = new auth();
    if($auth_controller->check_access($module,$action)){
        if (!class_exists($module)) {
            include "modules/" . $module . "/controller/controller.php";
        }

        $controller = new $module();

        if ($action) {
            if ($param) {
                return  $controller->{$action}($param);
            } else {
                return  $controller->{$action}();
            }
        } else {
            return $controller->index();
        }
    }else{
        if (!class_exists("forbidden")) {
            include_once "modules/forbidden/controller/controller.php";

        }
        $forbidden_controller = new forbidden();
        $forbidden_controller->view->render();
    }
```

i seen a  func like this , i dont know what happen in line 14 and 16 give me a hand and explain it.
i want to know how and  where we should use this kind of codes

Comment: _" I have problom"_ - what problem exactly? Share any error messages you are seeing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're talking about this line:

```
$controller->{$action}();
```

This it less complex than it looks. You're used to the syntax of normal class method calls, like this:

```
$controller->getOrderNumber();
```

In the code in your question the method name has been replace by a variable.

See [example 2 here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.variable-functions.php).

Note that the two lines below are equivalent:

```
$controller->{$action}();
$controller->$action();
```

I would use variable method names very sparingly. They make reading code and debugging more difficult. On top of that they might pose a security risk.

Comment: thank you , so line 14 mean : `$controller->$action($param);`